# Can't login with Symfony Guard, maybe because of cookies & multidomain

Tags: php, symfony, session, cookies

I need a very simple form login, so I'm using a Symfony Guard authenticator for this.

My application is multi-domain, for now login is possible on only 3 of them (and 2 are subdomains). But I can't log in on any of them.

First, here are some resources:

- The authenticator: [FormLoginAuthenticator.php](https://gist.github.com/Pierstoval/1e29a9badab1cba03e45a306aa658c83#file-formloginauthenticator-php)
- My security configuration: [https://gist.github.com/Pierstoval/1e29a9badab1cba03e45a306aa658c83#file-security-yaml)
- And in case it's needed, the session configuration in the framework: [config/packages/framework.yaml](https://gist.github.com/Pierstoval/1e29a9badab1cba03e45a306aa658c83#file-framework-yaml)

I don't understand why, but to debug this, I tried updating `config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml` to set `intercept_redirects: true`, to debug cookies and security config, and here's what I have when reproducing the common login scenario:

- When accessing the backend page (that shows the login form) I have the session cookie with a value like `llno5smlmsema5nq02kr30s6m2`.
- After I submit the form with correct values, I see the profiler's redirection page, and the Web Debug Toolbar shows me that I'm `Logged in as Pierstoval` and the session cookie sent by the response changes id and becomes `b1vbcnvp7e6p0j0o0vtd7ui7bf` (because by default the Firewall migrates the session when logging in), so this works. I can even see that the token is in the session. I also added `dump()` statements in the `Session::save()` method, and dumping session content shows the token. And the token is in the session file when I dump it too (in `var/sessions/dev/sess_b1vbcnvp7e6p0j0o0vtd7ui7bf`).
- I click on the `http://back.esteren.docker/fr/` link showed by the redirection page, and then I see the session cookie id did not change (it's the one that have been set after logging in), but this time, the Web Debug Toolbar shows me that I'm `Logged in as anon.`.

To me, there's a problem when the session is saved, so I took a look at the session files in `var/sessions/dev/`, **after the redirection**.

When I `cat var/sessions/dev/sess_b1vbcnvp7e6p0j0o0vtd7ui7bf`, I see this:

```
_sf2_attributes|a:2:{s:18:"_csrf/authenticate";s:43:"bCm23vBGyrq52caehAH9cCTjJkAmdT9j9Z8yygaET78";s:26:"_security.main.target_path";s:30:"http://back.esteren.docker/fr/";}_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1538092899;s:1:"c";i:1538092750;s:1:"l";s:5:"86400";}
```

Which, when unserializing the session attribute bag array, gives this:

```
array:2 [
  "_csrf/authenticate" => "bCm23vBGyrq52caehAH9cCTjJkAmdT9j9Z8yygaET78"
  "_security.main.target_path" => "http://back.esteren.docker/fr/"
]
```

This means the token has not been saved in the session after the successful login.

And even worse: since I already debugged the session file **before** redirecting, I **know** that it was saved ni the session and at some time it was **removed** from it before the session being saved another time.

How is this even possible? Did I forget something in my security configuration?

As a side-note, I tested with **and** without docker (with a plain php-fpm+nginx setup) and none worked, this probably means that it's not a permission issue from the docker side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, thanks to @Lynn and @Wirone on the public Symfony Slack channels, I ended up with a solution.

First, the bug was the fact that my User entity (which is serialized in the session) did not store the password.
And when a token is created, it checks if the "old" (in session) user password is the same as the "new" (refreshed) one, thanks to [the `Abstractoken::hasUserChanged()` method](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/a23a4a4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php#L234-L280).

And **if the user object has changed, the firewall logs the user out**.

To fix this, either serialize the password with the user, or implement `EquatableInterface` and use your own checks.

And this is what I did:

- Implement `EquatableInterface`
- Serialize only `id` and the timestampable fields `createdAt` and `updatedAt`
- Make `isEqualTo()` check class and date fields to know if the user has changed.

Hope this helps